# How to store child props to parent state in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-component, react-state

I have a `Parent` component which receives `child` and `onSubmit` props. The child is an arbitrary functional component with arbitrary props.

ex.

```
const Child = ( { name, onNameChange } ) => <> ... </>

// or

const Child = ( { description, onDescriptionChange } ) => <> ... </>
```

I want to store the props of the child inside the parent component in order for

1. the child to make changes to its own props (by using its own props)
2. the parent can use the child props in order to pass them on a submit function when a submit button is clicked.

```
const Parent = (
  {
    child: Child,
    onSubmit,
  },
) => {

  const childProps = 'What do I put here ?';
  
  const handleSubmit = () => {
    onSubmit(childProps);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Child { ...childProps } />
      <button onClick={ () => { return handleSubmit(); } }>Submit</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: Have you looked into using context? https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: How a context would help in my case ? The solution should still be agnostic to the ```childProps``` which is what I am struggling to find

Answer (score 0):

You can circumvent your problem by declaring the child's props in the component passing the child component to the parent component (aka the grandparent)

```js
const Parent = (
  {
    child: React.Node, // this child should already have the props it needs
    onSubmit: (model: any) => void, // wrap this function
  },
) => {
```

The grandparent can have an `onSubmit` method with the signature `(model: any) => void` and it can pass that to the parent. The parent can then wrap this `onSubmit` with it's own function handler and it will have access to the model. Then pass the modified handler to the `onClick`

Comment: But this is what i am trying to avoid. If I have a lot of ```Child``` components, I cannot start creating a lot of ```GrandParent``` components

Comment: Based on the code you provided, you must already have a grandparent. `Parent` is passed a `Child` prop and therefor something is defining what the child should be and passing it as a prop to the parent. There's no extra work involved.